# wxpython error on setup - ModuleNotFound: no module named 'wx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I'm having some trouble getting wxpython working on my mac. Here is a link to a tutorial that I am using: https://realpython.com/python-gui-with-wxpython/#getting-started-with-wxpython

The error message I am receiving is on the import of wx:
|| receiving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx' ||

- I have pip installed wxpython and pip3 installed wxpython just for good measure (sidenote: not sure of the difference, I'll google it)
  The package is properly shown in ||pip3 list|| terminal command.

I have also tried import wxpython as wx, in case that was an issue. No luck.

I have done some reading on the wxpython.org gitHub and readme, perhaps I missing some dependencies? Here is the prerequisites page:
https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst#prerequisites

They mention some sort of a build and wheel here: 
https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst#id2

I consider myself a little more experienced than a beginner at this stuff, but I have never read or heard of such terms above. The most work I have had to do to import some non-standard library was pip3 install x.

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='Hello World')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Expected result: a blank window with title "Hello World"
Actual result: error on line 1... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall using the same pip / pip3 tools, and then use this:

```
$ python -m pip install wxpython
```

The `-m` module syntax ensures that `sys.path` has the same value during installation as it will at runtime.

If still no joy, then first figure out where the binary wheel got installed to:

```
$ mdfind wx | egrep '/wx$'
```

or

```
$ find ~/miniconda3 ~ /usr / -name wx
```

(Hit CTRL-C once found.)

Then see if your path is searching in the right place:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
$ which python
$ python
>>> import pprint
>>> import sys
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
...
>>> import wx
>>>
```

The path is controlled by an env var.
Consider doing `$ export PYTHONPATH=/some/dir` before invoking the interpreter.

Comment: I appreciate the help! The reinstall using -m syntax worked like a charm. Any place you know where I can learn about those commands? I have seen them, just used them, and I'm not sure what they are called to google and learn more lol

Comment: Honestly, I don't really use `pip`, not if I can help it. I usually throw deps into an `environment.yml` file and then use The One Command: `conda env update`, cf https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/ (and yes, generally I _do_ wind up with a `- pip:` section in that file).